# When should I use type annotations for variables, arguments, and return types in Julia?

Tags: types, julia

In the [types section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/) of the docs, it's mentioned that

> The :: operator can be used to attach type annotations to expressions and variables in programs. There are two primary reasons to do this:
>
> 1. As an assertion to help confirm that your program works the way you expect,
> 2. To provide extra type information to the compiler, which can then improve performance in some cases

However, I can't find where is mentions in what "cases" specifically do type annotations help improve performance.

Quite surprisingly, it later mentions in the [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) section

> Type annotation will not enhance (and can actually hinder) performance if the type is abstract, or constructed at run-time.

It doesn't comprehensively discuss the cases where it would actually hinder performance so that they can be avoided.

I was looking for an answer for the question in the title in the docs. Despite how nice they are, I am now even further confused. Are there any simple rules to follow regarding when or when not to annotate types for the three cases in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one important case that was not covered by Antonello.

> I can't find where is mentions in what "cases" specifically do type annotations help improve performance.

The case when type annotation helps is when the type cannot be deduced in compile time. Here is an example:

```
julia> v = collect(Any, rand(1:10, 10^7));

julia> function f1(x::AbstractVector)
           s = 0
           for i in eachindex(x)
               v = x[i]
               a = v + v
               b = 2 + v
               c = v - 1
               d = a + c
               e = a - b + c - v
               s += e
           end
           return s
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f2(x::AbstractVector)
           s = 0
           for i in eachindex(x)
               v::Int = x[i]
               a = v + v
               b = 2 + v
               c = v - 1
               d = a + c
               e = a - b + c - v
               s += e
           end
           return s
       end
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time f1(v)
  1.055734 seconds (10.00 M allocations: 152.800 MiB, 1.03% gc time, 0.76% compilation time)
24995270

julia> @time f1(v)
  1.178262 seconds (10.00 M allocations: 152.585 MiB, 0.45% gc time)
24995270

julia> @time f2(v)
  0.688447 seconds (3.46 k allocations: 226.578 KiB, 1.75% compilation time)
24995270

julia> @time f2(v)
  0.716612 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
24995270

julia> function sum1(x::AbstractVector)
           s = 0
           for i in eachindex(x)
               v = x[i]
               s += v
           end
           return s
       end
sum1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function sum2(x::AbstractVector)
           s = 0
           for i in eachindex(x)
               v::Int = x[i]
               s += v
           end
           return s
       end
sum2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time sum1(v);
  0.260931 seconds (10.00 M allocations: 152.752 MiB, 17.27% gc time, 2.90% compilation time)

julia> @time sum1(v);
  0.227542 seconds (10.00 M allocations: 152.586 MiB, 2.32% gc time)

julia> @time sum2(v);
  0.738166 seconds (2.51 k allocations: 167.264 KiB, 1.08% compilation time)

julia> @time sum2(v);
  0.761652 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

What you see here is the fact that when we write `v::Int = x[i]` the code within the loop is type stable. When we write `v = x[i]` the code is not type stable and causes allocations.

You might then ask why `sum1` (not type stable) is faster than `sum2` (type stable). The reason is that when we write `v::Int = x[i]` it is not just type assertion. It is actually type conversion requirement, so e.g. if `x[i]` were `Bool` it would get converted to `Int`. The fact that the conversion is attempted is also costly. In `f1` and `f2` functions conversion cost is much smaller than the overhead caused by the operations on type unstable values. But in `sum1` and `sum2` functions the opposite is true.

In summary - things are not obvious (and even might change across Julia versions). That is why the Julia Manual cannot give you a precise rule.

---

Also what is relevant to know is that:

- when you annotate a variable or return value of a function **conversion is attempted**
- when you annotate function parameter **conversion is not attempted** (this annotation is used for dispatch)

Comment: Could you explain or refer me to a source that explains the cases where the compiler is unable to deduce the type of a variable? After your and @Antonello answers it's somewhat clearer to me when to annotate arguments and variables. 

How about return types, is there any value in annotating them? It would be odd that someone uses them to cast their return type to something else instead of explicitly doing that.

Comment: Return type annotation: Personally I use it rarely, only in cases when I want to make sure the function returns some type and signal to the compiler and other people what the function guarantees to return. The rule when the compiler is able to infer variable types is given here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#man-type-stability, however, it takes some experience to learn to think the way "compiler thinks" (i.e. I usually instantly know if I need to annotate or not, but this is because I use Julia a lot; using `@code_warntype` macro will help you to learn it).

Answer (score 2):

As function argument you annotate for assertion or to implement multiple dispatch, but not for performances.

The same in general for variable annotation, except one specific case that is struct members, where annotation of all members will make a big difference.

Comment: Does it hurt performance if the types used for annotation are abstract? In other words, consider no need for another dispatch and that docstring illustrates the types, then is it recommended to annotate types of function arguments when they are abstract?